# How to run website locally?

Tags: php, website, localhost

Windows 10 OS

basically I want to run a php website offline, in my PC-locally, so that i can use it without internet.

Is it possible, to run locally as an offline-app

please tell me basic steps to achieve this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: We expect each question to show reasonable research effort. Have you tried searching for "host index.php locally". This is what I've got from google: [PHP server on local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1678010/10765659). You haven't told us your OS. May the first "basic step" be "install Linux"? Or do you want to keep your current OS? What is your OS then?

Comment: sorry for those mistakes, I have updated the question

Comment: Do you want to run that website, or do you want to take the repository offline?

Comment: what do, take repository offline mean?.. download master-zip ?.. i have already downloaded the master zip, and was trying to Run locally, so i can use it as an offline-app.

Comment: Please explain why you want to run this site offline. What is your goal?

Comment: to use it offline, in areas without internet?... like in village home.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an appropriate Windows Edition, you can enable the "Internet Information Services" (aka IIS) feature from add/remove Windows components.

You can then set up the application in IIS with an application pool.

Alternatively, set up a local Apache web server on your machine.

If all of that sounds too complicated, then you'll need to do some research on how to set up a local development environment. There is no go-to step-by-step guide, as it depends on the application being developed.